# Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fix an error on my PHP code. Could you please help me?

This is the code:

```
function get_posts($id = null , $cat_id = null ) {
    $posts = array();
    $query = "SELECT `posts`.`id` AS `post_id`, `categories_id`.`id` AS `category_id`,
                     `title`, `contents`, `date_posted`, categories`.`name` 
              FROM `posts`
              INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`cat_id`
              ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC";

    $query = mysql_query($query);

    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $posts[] = $row;
    }
    echo mysql_error();
    return $posts;
}
```

and I get:

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\func\blog.php on line 89

Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'field list'

Comment: As scary as it sounds, is it possible that the table `posts` does not have a column called `id`?

Comment: It has, the first column is id.

Comment: My bet is that you aren't looking at the database/schema you think you're looking at.

Comment: On windows machines, the use of capitalization makes no difference, but it would make a difference on linux/unix (maybe Mac, never played with em) machines. Have you looked at how the table was created? PHPMyAdmin changes everything to lowercase so don't use that. Check it in the console using `show columns from yourTable;`

Comment: [link](http://tinypic.com/r/eapmok/8) this is my structure. I don't know what is wrong

Comment: @nel_3001 I am hoping we have a solution :) (answer posted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I went to look at your query to format it nicely, it turned out that you missed a backtick:

```
SELECT 
    `posts`.`id` AS `post_id`, 
    //`categories_id`.`id` AS `category_id`,
    // ^^ This was also incorrectly used. Your table is called categories
    `categories`.`id` AS `category_id`,
    `title`, 
    `contents`, 
    `date_posted`, 
    `categories`.`name`
    // ^^ You missed the first backtick
FROM 
    `posts`
        INNER JOIN `categories` 
            ON `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`cat_id`
ORDER BY 
    `posts`.`id` DESC
```

Edit: As per my comment before I posted this answer:

On windows machines, the use of capitalization makes no difference, but it would make a difference on linux/unix (maybe Mac, never played with em) machines. Have you looked at how the table was created? PHPMyAdmin changes everything to lowercase so don't use that. Check it in the console using show columns from yourTable;

Comment: Same error with your query. I wonder, does phpMyAdmin version have something to do with it?

Comment: I remade the database and now i get: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\func\blog.php on line 98
Unknown column 'categories_id.id' in 'field list'    and on line 98 there is $posts[] = $row;

Comment: Solved it. Looked like 'categories_id'.'id' was actually 'categories'.'id'

Comment: HAHAHAA, I just edited to resolve that.

Comment: Would you mind voting  to close as a typo question, please?

Comment: @nel_3001 Don't take it peronsonally, but it is unlikely that this question will help further users on the site. Closing it might not redirect google searchers from it, but if we have solved your issues, the site is working as intended.